# Injectivity of Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that cantor function is not injective since $f(\frac{1}{3}) = f(\frac{2}{3})$.

But I have a problem which asks me to prove that the only points where the function is not injective are exactly the end points of removed open middle thirds.
How can I start with that?
Thanks & regards

Comment: Th Cantor function is a constant on each of the intervals removed.

Comment: The book I am following considers the domain to be the cantor set only @KaviRamaMurthy